# Passing R object to nested loops

Tags: r, loops

```
myfun1 = function(dummy){
  dummy = dummy
  x2 = x.rand + 1
  return(x2)
}

myfun2 = function(dummy2){
  dummy2 = dummy2
  x.rand = rnorm(10)
  myfun1(dummy2)
}

> myfun2(3)
```

> Error in myfun1(dummy2) : object 'x.rand' not found

I have an inner function `myfun1` that can only take in 1 parameter (`dummy`) and adds 1 to my `x.rand` vector. I also have an outer function `myfun2` which defines the `x.rand` vector as a random sample of normal distribution. My goal is to be able to pass in the `x.rand` object into `myfun1`. How exactly can I do this without making it a parameter?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971217/how-to-pass-object-in-nested-functions) post here using `save()` but I don't really understand it...and am wondering if there is an easier way?

Comment: Guess you could use `x.rand <<- rnorm(10)` to assign `x.rand` to the global env. ... works, but comes with many downsides and is typically avoided.

Comment: Why would you not want to make it a parameter?

Comment: Another alternative is to define myfun1 inside of myfun2. It will then have access to objects inside of myfun2's environment.

Comment: @FlorianMaas `myfun1` is supposed to be the objective function which I pass into a `nmkb(fn = myfun1, par = c(...))` function call. And it can only take in 1 parameter (i.e. the `par = c(...)`). I would like to pass in another one other than just `par = c(...)`

Comment: Alternatively, you could maybe return list(dummy1,x.rand) from fun2, and use that as a single input argument in fun1, as dummy = input_list[[1]] and x.rand = input_list[[2]]. Not sure if that helps, but just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the function takes only one input argument:

```
myfun1 = function(input_list){
  dummy = input_list[[1]]
  x2 = input_list[[2]] + 1
  return(x2)
}

myfun2 = function(dummy2){
  dummy2 = dummy2
  x.rand = rnorm(10)
  myfun1(list(dummy2,x.rand))
}

myfun2(3)
```

Not sure if this is what you needed though. But technically, it only has a single input parameter and it has access to the x.rand vector.